# Unable to receive cookie when refresh route is accessed from frontend

Tags: express, cookies, axios, cors

In the backend, the login route generates access and refresh tokens and stores the refresh token in a httpOnly cookie. The refresh route generates accessToken if the cookie is present. Everything works fine in the backend part as expected. In the frontend, I'm trying to access the refresh route through a custom hook but it returns 401 Unauthorized. On console logging req.cookies in the refresh route,  **[Object: null prototype] {}** is logged. By reading upon possible errors, I think it can possibly be a cors error since testing the backend part logs a valid cookie to the console.

Login

```
export const login = expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  if (!email || !password) {
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error('All fields are required');
  }

  const user = await User.findOne({ email });

  if (user && (await user.matchPassword(password))) {
    const accessToken = generateAccessToken(user._id, user.role);
    const refreshToken = generateRefreshToken(user._id);

    const role = user.role;

    res.cookie('jwt', refreshToken, {
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: false,
      sameSite: 'None',
      maxAge: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    });
    res.json({ accessToken, role });
  } else {
    res.status(401);
    throw new Error('Invalid email or password');
  }
});
```

Refresh

```
export const refresh = expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const cookies = req.cookies;
  console.log(cookies);

  if (!cookies?.jwt) {
    res.status(401);
    throw new Error('Unauthorized');
  }

  const refreshToken = cookies.jwt;

  jwt.verify(
    refreshToken,
    process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET,
    async (err, decoded) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(403);
        throw new Error('Forbidden');
      }
      const foundUser = await User.findById(decoded.id);
      if (!foundUser) {
        res.status(401);
        throw new Error('Unauthorized');
      }

      const accessToken = generateAccessToken(foundUser.id);
      res.json({ accessToken });
    }
  );
});
```

useRefreshToken

```
import axios from '../api/axios';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const useRefreshToken = () => {
  const userInfo = useSelector((state) => state.auth.userInfo);

  const refresh = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get('/auth/refresh', {
      withCredentials: true,
    });
    console.log(response.data.accessToken);
    return response?.data?.accessToken;
  };
  return refresh;
};

export default useRefreshToken;
```

CorsOptions

```
import allowedOrigins from './allowedOrigins.js';

const corsOption = {
  origin: (origin, callback) => {
    if (allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) !== -1 || !origin) {
      callback(null, true);
    } else {
      callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'));
    }
  },
  credentials: true,
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
};

export default corsOption;
```

Comment: In Chrome, `SameSite=None` also requires `Secure`.

Comment: @jub0bs I tried adding secure=true but it does not change anything. Still getting 401 Unauthorized error when trying to access from frontend

Comment: Since your are not making any cross-site requests (`GET /auth/refresh` is within the same origin), you don't need `SameSite=None` and can also omit the `{withCredentials: true}`.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen Indeed. Good catch.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen it still gives the 401 Unauthorized error. Also, the cookie is not visible under the application tab of Developer Tools